# Not able to draw multiple images

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jcomponent

I am not able to draw all lines. When I run this code, only 3 of the 4 lines are drawn. If I only had 3 constructor calls to draw lines, only 2 lines are drawn. Can someone help me fix this?

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(500, 500);


            JPanel pane = new JPanel();
            pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            pane.add(new JComponent() {
                public void paint(Graphics g) {
                    new Lines(120, 30, 200, 30).paint(g, this);
                    new Lines(120, 60, 120, 30).paint(g, this);
                    new Lines(200, 60, 200, 30).paint(g, this);
                    new Lines(120, 60, 200, 30).paint(g, this);
                }
            });

            frame.add(pane);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR0Co.png)

This is my Lines class btw, could someone help me why only certain lines are drawn and how I can fix this:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Lines {

    //variables
    static int x0, x1, y0, y1, x, y, n;
    static double dx, dy, m, b;
    static int uslope = 0;

    public Lines(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        x0 = a;
        y0 = b;
        x1 = c;
        y1 = d;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g, ImageObserver observer) {

        //finding the variables for linear function (non vertical line)

        if ((x1 - x0) != 0 || (x0 - x1) != 0) {
            dx = x1 - x0;
            dy = y1 - y0;
            m = dy / dx;
            b = y0 - (m * x0);
        } else {
            //in case a vertical line
            uslope = 1;
        }

        //line thickness and pixels
        Color black = new Color(0, 0, 0);
        int rgb = black.getRGB();
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(2, 2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        img.setRGB(1, 1, rgb);

        /*
         * Each case depends on the value of m and if the value of the starting x or y coordinate is greater than the ending x or y coordinate
         */

        //vertical line drawing to higher y value (y0 < y1)
        if ((uslope == 1) && (y0 < y1)) {
            for (int i = y0; i <= y1; i++) {
                x = x0;
                y = i;
                g.drawImage(img, x, y, observer);
            }
        }
        //vertical line drawing from higher y value (y0 > y1)
        else if ((uslope == 1) && (y1 < y0)) {
            for (int i = y0; i >= y1; i--) {
                x = x0;
                y = i;
                g.drawImage(img, x, y, observer);
            }
        }
        //horizontal line drawing to higher x value (x0 < x1)
        else if ((m == 0) && (x0 < x1)) {
            for (int i = x0; i <= x1; i++) {
                x = i;
                y = y0;
                g.drawImage(img, x, y, observer);
            }
        }
        //horizontal line drawing from higher x value (x0 > x1)
        else if ((m == 0) && (x1 < x0)) {
            for (int i = x0; i >= x1; i--) {
                x = i;
                y = y0;
                g.drawImage(img, x, y, observer);
            }
        }
        //positive m-slope line drawing to higher x value (x1 > x0)
        else if ((m > 0) && (x0 < x1)) {
            for (int i = x0; i <= x1; i++) {
                x = i;
                y = (int) ((m * x) + b);
                g.drawImage(img, x, y, observer);
            }
        }
        //positive m-slope line drawing from higher x value (x0 > x1)
        else if ((m > 0) && (x1 < x0)) {
            for (int i = x0; i >= x1; i--) {
                x = i;
                y = (int) ((m * x) + b);
                g.drawImage(img, x, y, observer);
            }
        }
        //negative m-slope line drawing to higher x value (x1 > x0)
        else if ((m < 0) && (x0 < x1)) {
            for (int i = x0; i <= x1; i++) {
                x = i;
                y = (int) ((m * x) + b);
                g.drawImage(img, x, y, observer);
            }
        }
        //negative m-slope line drawing from higher x value (x0 > x1)
        else if ((m < 0) && (x1 < x0)) {
            for (int i = x0; i >= x1; i--) {
                x = i;
                y = (int) ((m * x) + b);
                g.drawImage(img, x, y, observer);
            }
        } else
            System.out.println("error");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to draw simple lines, use Graphisc2D.drawLine. If the issue is more complex, I think, the bug is in this strange calculation - 'y = (int) ((m * x) + b);'. But it'ss hard to understand what you want exactly.

Comment: I have to use that class to draw lines pixel by pixel. I must draw multiple lines using that class.

Answer (score 3):

> I am not able to draw all lines.

```
static int x0, x1, y0, y1, x, y, n;
static double dx, dy, m, b;
static int uslope = 0;
```

Don't use static variables. Each class should have its own instance variables.

Other comments:

1. Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)` not paint()
2. Don't create new instances of objects in your painting method. Every time Swing determines the component needs to be painted you keep creating new objects. This in not very efficient. A painting method should just paint the current state on an object. Instead you should have an ArrayList of objects you want to paint. Then in the painting method you just iterate through the ArrayList to paint each object.

Comment: I have actually tested the effect of removing "static", and can confirm that this fixes the problem.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: I am not OP :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of painting the lines with your own class, I would recommend painting them with `Graphics2D` from `java.awt`, this is easier and would look like this:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500, 500);


    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pane.add(new JComponent() {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
            g2d.drawLine(120,60,200,30);
            g2d.drawLine(120,30,200,30);
            g2d.drawLine(120,60,120,30);
            g2d.drawLine(200,60,200,30);

        }
    });

    frame.add(pane);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: That would be much easier, but I must draw pixel by pixel and the class works perfectly fine, but I could not figure out the bug not allowing some lines to draw

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in my code.
The draw methodes of Grafics usally miss the first pixels\lines to draw.
You need to draw somethings before and remove them.

Comment: (1-) This is not true. The draw methods will draw what you tell them to.

Comment: In my program, it miss the firsts lines and draw the others.

Comment: The problem is with your program, not the Graphics draw methods. If you have a problem with your application the create an [mre] and ask a question. This is not the solution for this problem.  check out my answer to see the solution. It is easy to test. Just copy/paste, remove the "static" keywords, compile and test.